# VBA as front end of R

Tags: r, vba, shell

I am want to automate my report which I crated regularly. I want to use R as backend tool. I am trying to run above below VBA code to run my R script but I am not getting any final output file written. Can anybody help or suggest where I am making mistake. I have limited knowledge of VBA codes

```
Sub R_Click()
   'runs an external R code through Shell
   Dim shell As Object
   Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
   Dim style As Integer: style = 1
   Dim errorCode As Integer
   Dim path As String
   path = """C:\Users\syed-salman\Documents\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64\RScript""" & " " & "C:\02. Custom Request\1. Hospitality Survey -2019\Project\R Codes\Custom Project - MERCER\Final_Hotel Survey.R"
   errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

I want to use R for backend calculation and generate for me without opening the R

```
rm(list=ls())

list.of.packages <- c("dplyr","readxl", "stringr")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)>0 ) install.packages(new.packages)

library(readxl)
# library(rJava)
# library(xlsx)   # Download Java https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

WorkingDir <- getwd()
Folder <- read_xlsx("settings.xlsx", sheet = "Folder_Name")
FOLDER <- paste(Folder$ACTIVITY[1], "_", Folder$Year[1], sep = "")
dir.create(as.character(paste(FOLDER,"", sep="")))
year <- paste(Folder$Year[1], sep = "")


mod <- read_xlsx("ID_Mod_FLAG.xlsx") # updated the file name the bracket

mod_flag <- mod

#Rename the columns
#colnames(mod_flag)[colnames(mod_flag)=='PNAME_POS_TYPE'] <- "Type_Position"
#colnames(mod_flag)[colnames(mod_flag)=='PROPERTY_PROP_CITY'] <- "City"
#colnames(mod_flag)[colnames(mod_flag)=='OBJECTID'] <- "OBJECTID"

mod_flag <- mod_flag %>% 
    mutate(All = 'H',
           KP = ifelse(PNAME_POS_TYPE == 'Key Position', "KP", ""),
           AP = 'AP',
           # FLAG_AP = ifelse(PNAME_POS_TYPE == 'Target Position', "AP", ""),
           City_Code = substr(PROPERTY_PROP_CITY, 1, 1))



mod_flag <-  mod_flag %>% mutate(
    FLAG01 = ifelse(PNAME_POS_TYPE == 'Key Position', paste(All,KP, ";", sep = ""), ""), #mod_all_key_flag
    FLAG02 = paste(All, AP, ";", sep = ""), #mod_all_tar_flag
    FLAG03 = ifelse(PNAME_POS_TYPE == 'Key Position', paste(City_Code, KP, ";", sep = ""), ""), #mod_kp_city
    FLAG04 = paste(City_Code, AP, ";", sep = ""), #mod_ap_city
)

ix <- grep("*FLAG", names(mod_flag))
Paste <- function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = "")
# Final_file <- data.frame(OBJECTID = mod_flag$OBJEC, MOD_FLAG = apply(mod_flag[ix], 1, Paste))


Final_file <- mod_flag %>% 
    mutate(MOD_FLAG = apply(mod_flag[ix], 1, Paste))

drop <- c("All", "KP", "AP", "City_Code", "FLAG01", "FLAG02", "FLAG03", "FLAG04")

Final_file <- Final_file[, -which(names(mod_flag) %in% drop)]

d <-format(Sys.time(), "_%a %d-%m-%Y %I%M%S")
filename <- paste(d, ".csv", sep = "")

setwd(file.path(WorkingDir, as.character(paste(FOLDER,"", sep=""))))


lapply(split(Final_file, Final_file$PROPERTY_PROP_CTRY),
       function(x)write.csv(x, file = paste(x$PROPERTY_PROP_CTRY[1], filename ), row.names = FALSE))


write.csv(Final_file, "Final_METADATA.csv", row.names = FALSE)

setwd(WorkingDir)
```

Comment: modify your path variable to path = path & " & pause".  this will keep the cmd prompt open and you will be able to see any error msges from your r code

Comment: Also make sure to double quote the path to your R file, as it has multiple spaces.

Comment: Why not just use a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you didn't put any double quotes `""` on your argument that contains several spaces.

I tested this code on my Excel and it works (with different paths of course):

```
Sub R_Click()
   'runs an external R code through Shell
   Dim shell As Object
   Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
   Dim style As Integer: style = 1
   Dim errorCode As Integer
   Dim rCommand As String
   rCommand = """C:\Users\syed-salman\Documents\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64\RScript.exe"" ""C:\02. Custom Request\1. Hospitality Survey -2019\Project\R Codes\Custom Project - MERCER\Final_Hotel Survey.R"" && pause"
   errorCode = shell.Run(rCommand, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

> **Note**: I added `&& pause` at the end of the command to show the result, but you can delete it and it will work.

Hope this helps.